# How to generate equally distributed random numbers in a range and with decimal places in bash?

Tags: bash, random, decimal

How can I generate equally distributed random numbers in a range and with p.e, 2 or 5 decimal places in bash without to use AWK or bc ?

Bash usually only supports whole numbers. However, numbers with decimal places can be used in bash, e.g. with the command sleep:
sleep 1.23456 # sleep time in s

Given is the following example, which can generate with bash in a range from 0 to 10, equally distributed random numbers without decimal places.

```
ug_rnd=0
og_rnd=10

rnd="$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"
        my_rnd=$((rnd%(og_rnd-ug_rnd+1)+ug_rnd));        
        echo "$my_rnd"

sleep "$my_rnd"
```

Comment: `sleep` is not part of `bash`. `sleep 1.23456` simply passes a string to the external command `sleep` which parses the string as a floating-point value.

Comment: I would just use `awk`, which has both a random-number generator built-in and and control how many decimal places are output.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use `awk` (or something similar)?

Comment: `bash` doesn't do floating-point arithmetic. You'd have to use something like `bc`, but then why not use `awk` instead of `bc` and `dd`?

Comment: Please explain your requirements better. Why not use appropriate tools?

Comment: You are basically picking the worst possible language to implement this in. *Why?*

Comment: Different people preffer different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you're currently generating random numbers between `0` and `10` and you want to add 2 decimal places.

Consider generating random numbers between `0` and `1000` (`10 * 10^2`), split the result into 2x chunks and then piece together with a decimal.

A rough example:

**NOTE:** Added Kamilcuk's comment re: using `printf` to take care of left padding numbers with `0's`

```
$ x=735           # assume this is our random number (between 0 and 1000)
$ absx="${x#-}"   # if x is negative we need to strip off '-' for 2nd calculation to keep from generating "-7.-35"

$ printf -v newx "%d.%02d" "$(( x / 100 ))" "$(( absx % 100 ))" 
$ echo "${newx}"
7.35

$ time sleep "${newx}"

real    0m7.375s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

If OP wants 4 decimal places then generate a random number between `0` and `100000` (`10 x 10^4`), and replace the `100` entries (in the `newx` split-n-piece-together operation) with `10000`.

Shouldn't be too hard to add some logic to current code to figure out the multiplier (`10^<number_of_decimals>`), set `og_rnd=$((10*<multiplier))`, and replace `100` with the `<multiplier>` variable in the split-n-piece-together operation.

Comment: Weeeelll, you can also do it on strings: `${x::-2}.${x: -2}` `additional checks to address 'small' numbers` - do `printf "%d.%02d" "$((...))" "$((...))"` Also - `x-(x/100*100)` -> just `x%100`

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, I started out with that idea and then went with the 'math' solution (with view towards supporting a dynamic number of decimal digits); granted, the string manipulation you suggest can also be modified to support dynamic number of digits; feel free to post an answer if you wish

Comment: that just shows the `sleep` command ran for `7.35` seconds (actually a tad bit more due to overhead of running within a `time` wrapper

Comment: @linda54 updated the answer to create a new variable `absx` (`abs`olute(`x`)) which just strips off the `-` before performing the 2nd calculation; you could alternatively push this down into the 2nd calculation like such: `"$(( ${x#-} % 100 ))"`

Comment: we've meandered a good bit from the original question; at this point I'd suggest creating a new question, provide your latest/updated code, and the case(s) where you're still seeing issues ... to include the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 0):

I played with this while you guys were talking about it. My suggestion was similar, kinda...

```
 range=100 scale=5; w=$((${#range}+scale)); 
 printf "%0$w.${scale}f\n" "$((RANDOM%$range)).$(
   s=$scale; while ((s--)); do printf "%s" $((RANDOM%10)); done
 )"
```

I still think `awk` is a much better solution, though.

Comment: I get the follow error message: bash: printf: 3.37168: Not valide count

Answer (score 0):

Checking the best voted answer:

Good looking:

```
$ x=735           # assume this is our random number (between 0 and 1000)
$ absx="${x#-}"   # if x is negative we need to strip off '-' for 2nd calculation to keep from generating "-7.-35"

$ printf -v newx "%d.%02d" "$(( x / 100 ))" "$(( absx % 100 ))" 
$ echo "${newx}"
7.35
```

Also good looking:

```
$ x=-735           # assume this is our random number (between 0 and 1000)
$ absx="${x#-}"   # if x is negative we need to strip off '-' for 2nd calculation to keep from generating "-7.-35"
       
$ printf -v newx "%d.%02d" "$(( x / 100 ))" "$(( absx % 100 ))" 
$ echo "${newx}"
-7.35
```

Wrong result:

```
$ x=-50           # assume this is our random number (between 0 and 1000)
$ absx="${x#-}"   # if x is negative we need to strip off '-' for 2nd calculation to keep from generating "-7.-35"
       
$ printf -v newx "%d.%02d" "$(( x / 100 ))" "$(( absx % 100 ))" 
$ echo "${newx}"
0.50
```

Range which give wrong results:

Input:

```
x=-1 ... - 99
```

Output:

```
newx= 0.01 ... 0.99
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the issue with the latest result is that `bash` does integer math so `-50/100` equals `0` (and not `-0`) so the final answer is `0.50`; you could add yet another piece of code that a)  uses `absx` for both calculations and b) if `x` is less than `0` then add a `-` to `newx`; we've gone round and round on this question now, finding more and more issues all because ... as others have pointed out in the comments (above) ... `bash` is not the right tool for floating point / non-integer operations

Answer (score -1):

Its looks its possible and easy: Equally distributed random numbers in a range and with decimal places, created by bash.

Its need a fix if the counts between 0 and 1 or 0 and -1.

```
#!/bin/bash

ug_rnd=-5
og_rnd=5
decimal_places=2

while true; do

decimal_places_faktor=$((10**decimal_places))

ug_rnd_new=$((ug_rnd*decimal_places_faktor))
og_rnd_new=$((og_rnd*decimal_places_faktor))

rnd="$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"
my_rnd=$((rnd%(og_rnd_new-ug_rnd_new+1)+ug_rnd_new));        
echo "$my_rnd"
echo
echo

echo "var_left"
var_left=${my_rnd::$((${#my_rnd}-decimal_places))}
echo "$var_left"
echo
echo

echo "var_right"
var_right=${my_rnd:$((${#my_rnd}-decimal_places))}
echo "$var_right"
echo
echo
echo "Equal distributed random count incl. decimal places in bash"
echo "$var_left.$var_right"
echo
echo

sleep 1

done

$ -2.23559 # Can generate positive an negative values.
```

Comment: see the update to my answer; the simple solution is to strip out the `-` before performing the 2nd calculation; one update to your code would be to replace `$(($my_rnd%decimal_places_faktor))` with `$(( ${my_rnd#-} % decimal_places_faktor ))`; alternatively create a new variable with the `-` stripped off and then use this new variable in the calculation